# Setting json formatter in monolog

Tags: php, logging, monolog

How can the logs be set to **json format** in **monolog**....

```
$logger = new StreamHandler(__DIR__.'/my_app.log');
$logger->setFormatter( new JsonFormatter() );
$logger->pushHandler($logger);
```

This doesn't seems to be correct as it shows error

> Call to undefined method Monolog\Logger::setFormatter()

also I would like my log to be recorded like this:

```
message{
a="something";
b="something else"
}
```

instead of:

```
message{a="something";b="something else"}
```

Comment: You don't push a logger on to itself, you push it to the main Monolog logger instance. Also the way you want your log to be formatted is not valid JSON, so you'd have to create your own custom formatter in that case.

Answer (score 1):

In case some other person has this question also: The formatter can be set to the handler, not the logger.

```php
use Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

$logger = new Logger('your_channel_name');
$handler = new StreamHandler('your/dir.log');
$handler->setFormatter( new JsonFormatter() );
$logger->pushHandler($handler);

// and then where ever in the code
$logger->info('your message', ["var1" => "value 1", "otherVar" => "otherValue"]);

// it will result in a parsable output similar to this:
// {
//   "message":"your message",
//   "context": {
//      "var1":"value 1", 
//      "otherVar":"otherValue"
//   }, 
//   "level":200, 
//   "level_name":"INFO",  
//   "channel":"your_channel_name",
//   "datetime":"2021-06-25T10:54:10.116817+00:00",
//   "extra":{}
// }
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md) itself is not the best, but a start as well.